# Group by one column and show counts

Tags: sql, postgresql

I had a complicated Query that I can summarize as:

```
select t0.A, t1.B, t0.C, x.count from T0 t0 
join
(
    select distinct max(D) over (partition by A order by D desc) as D,
    count(t2.A) over (partition by t0.A)
        from T0 t0 join T2 t2 on t2.E = t0.D
        where t0.B = k
) x on t0.D = x.D
join T1 t1 on t1.B = t0.B
    where not exists(select A from T2 t2 where t2.A = t0.A)
```

Which gave the desired output, for example:

```
 A     B     C    count
===   ===   ===   ===
id1   name1 sadf  3
id2   name2 dgds  2
id3   name3 dfbg  1
```

but ran way too slow. After running analyze I found the culprit to be the `count` inside the first `join`.

So I'm trying to take the `count` out of the first `join` so it can run on fewer rows (if I understand correctly)., but I don't really know how to proceed. So far I have written:

```
select t0.A, t1.B, t0.C from T0 t0 
join
(
    select distinct max(E) over (partition by t0.A order by E desc) as D,
) x on t0.D = x.D
join T2 t2 on t2.E = t0.D
join T1 t1 on t1.B = t0.B
    where not exists(select A from T2 t2 where t2.A = t0.A)
```

Which gives output like:

```
 A     B     C  
===   ===   === 
id1   name1 sadf
id2   name2 dgds
id1   name1 xfga
id1   name1 sadf
id2   name2 nuoh
id3   name3 dfbg
```

But as above I want it grouped by column A regardless of the value in column C (i.e. not just grouped by duplicate rows, two of the same A values could have the same or different C values), and I want to show counts as above too.

Putting `group by t0.A` at the bottom just gives an error:

```
ERROR: column "t1.B" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

And I have no idea where to put `count`

Please help!

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain what you want the query to do?  Sample data (to match the desired output) would be a big help.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what I need to add. Could you give an example?

Comment: What is the data in the various tables that produces the output that you show in the beginning of the question?  You should be able to explain what the query is supposed to do.  At the very least, you can edit the question and fix the syntactic errors in the SQL.

Comment: I don't think I can do that with my current level of understanding. This is my first time working with SQL. I thought that it would be possible to look at the second query I wrote and figure out how group the output of that query by column A and show a count for each group. For example if you gave me the output of my query I could just do something like d = defaultdict(int) for row in output d[row.A] += 1, but I need to do this in SQL.

Comment: You claim you got results, but `count(x.A over (partition by t0.A)` is invalid syntax (among other things). Please fix your question.

Comment: Fixed hopefully. Sorry I had to cut down the original query for my question and also make up table and column names since the original names where very long and not helpful or descriptive.

Comment: Not fixed. How can anybody answer when you neither provide the actual query nor *anything* else to describe your actual situation?

Comment: Do you care what value comes out in B or C? Seems you don't as long as A, B, C is one of the entries in those tables?

Comment: I do not care what comes out in B or C, but with my solution I noticed I am not necessarily preserving rows. I might be pulling a B from one row and a C from another row which each have the same A.

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid and simplified version of what you posted so far. Just an educated guess.

```
SELECT t0.a, max(t1.b) AS max_b, max(t0.c) AS max_c, count(t0.a) AS ct_a
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT max(d) AS max_d
   FROM   t0
   GROUP  BY a
   ) x
JOIN   t0 ON t0.e = x.max_d
JOIN   t2 USING (d)
JOIN   t1 USING (b)
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE a = t0.a)
GROUP  BY t0.a;
```